# Customize function defaults using external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running through a small test and stumbling on what seems should be really simple. If I have an index.html file with the following script:

```
var runtime = (function(){

    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    function Runtime(){
        this.$jq = $jq;
    }

    Runtime.prototype.initialize = function( _callback ){
        var self = this;
        this.$jq.getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js", function(){
            $('aside').accordion();
            _callback.apply(self, [self.$jq]);
        });
    } 
// -- more unrelated methods here
return new Runtime();
})();
```

And I want to alter the default jquery ui accordion behavior using a separate js file. Specifically I would like to kill the accordion animation. The jquery-ui api requires a simple 'animate: false'. how do I proceed?

separate .js file:

```
runtime.initialize(function( $ ){

 // Disable animation on the accordion here
 // with 'animate: false'

})
```

Can I even access this method from the external file?

Comment: use accordion api to change options

Comment: @charlietfl I can't touch the index.html file. I understand that the accordion api has this available setting: 'animate: false', but I want to implement using the external js file. Will update/edit original to reiterate this point

Comment: right, in the `initialize` callback you can do it. It runs after accordion is initialized. Use the `option` setting method https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option

Comment: @charlietfl great that confirms I CAN do it, but i'm striking out on the 'how' part - most often getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function'. Any type of hint you can offer as to how I can access the instance of the function that is already created?

Comment: because `$` was voided by noConflict()...need to use `runtime.$jq(selector).accordion` or `jQuery(selector).....`

Comment: @charlietfl Yessah! jQuery(selector) was the way to go! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here stemmed from

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

as @charlietfl pointed out in the comments

I just needed to use the option setting method as specified in the api, but do so using 'jQuery' to define the jquery object (vs $):

```
jQuery('aside').accordion("option","animate", false);
```